# Guard checking of lambdas

Tags: c#, validation, lambda, guard-clause

I usually perform guard checking like so:

```
public void doStuff(Foo bar, Expression<Func<int, string>> pred) {
  if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
  if (pred == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
  // etc...
}
```

I've seen this extra check which ensures that the predicate is actually a lambda:

```
  if (pred.NodeType != ExpressionType.Lambda) throw new ArgumentException();
```

The `ExpressionType` enum has many possibilities, but I don't understand how any of them would apply because I assumed the compiler would only allow a lambda.

Q1: *Is there benefit to this?* We do thorough guard checking of all inputs, so does this add value?

Q2: Is there a performance penalty - i.e. does it take longer than a regular type/bounds/null check?

Comment: Seems that Q1 benefits you if you *want* to make sure that your expression is of a certain type, rather than just null checking it.

Comment: @Glubus Could it be anything other than a lambda to begin with though?

Comment: Yes. Expressions are used  to describe and use the meta-data of the data it is holding. `Expression<<Func<int, string>>` describes a delegate that accepts an integer and returns a string, but does not actually define an instance of this delegate. This way you can create entire expression tree's by chaining them together. Checkout the mdsn article about the Expression class.

Comment: @Glubus what do you think of answer by jlvaquero

Comment: It's correct, since your parameter is of type `Expression<Func<int, string>>`, `pred` will always be `Expression.Lambda`. I probably made this confusing because I thought for a while you were talking about the `Expression` class in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Func<int, string>` is a delegate that could be the address of a function or inline as lambda expression [ `() => x` ] .

`Expression<TDelegate>` inherits from LambdaExpression and the `NodeType` of an `Expression<TDelegate>` is always `ExpressionType.Lambda.`

So, I think that kind of defensive code is not needed.

Comment: Yeah that's was my thinking. I don't see how it can be anything else in this case.